# Output array to element classes

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm trying to output a JSON object to different parts of an HTML page using the same classes.

I'm importing my JSON from an API but when I've put information into it (via input fields) it looks a little bit like this:

```
    {  
     "trip": [
             { // the first object in the trip-array
         "leg": [{
               "tripid": "0",
               "origin": {
                     "name": "New York",
                     "time": "12:04"
                },
               "destination": {
                     "name": "Albany",
                     "time": "1:49"
               }
             },{
               "tripid": "1",
               "origin": {
                     "name": "Albany",
                     "time": "2:05"
                },
               "destination": {
                     "name": "Boston",
                     "time": "3:12"
                }
              }]
             },
            { // the second object in the trip-array
         "leg": [{
               "tripid": "0",
               "origin": {
                     "name": "New York",
                     "time": "1:04"
                },
               "destination": {
                     "name": "Albany",
                     "time": "2:49"
               }
             },{
               "tripid": "1",
               "origin": {
                     "name": "Albany",
                     "time": "3:05"
                },
               "destination": {
                     "name": "Boston",
                     "time": "4:12"
                }
              }]
             }]
        }
```

I'm trying to display the information on my website, but I can't get it to behave the way I want it to.

The first time around I did it something like this (after fetching the JSON via my PHP-page):

```
function addDataToHTML(data){
    var trips = data.trip;
    $.each(trips, function(){  
        document.getElementById('show_all_results');
        var summary = document.createElement('div');
        summary.innerHTML = "<span class='origin_time'>" + this.leg[0].origin.time +
        "&nbsp;</span><span class='origin_name'>&nbsp;" + this.leg[0].origin.name + 
        "</span><span>-</span><span class='destination_time'>" + this.leg[leg.length-1].destination.time + 
        "&nbsp;</span><span class='destination_name'>&nbsp;" + this.leg[this.leg.length-1].destination.name + 
        "</span>";
        document.getElementById('show_all_results').appendChild(summary);
    });
}
```

This works but the problem I'm having is that I want to add a button in the code which would give me more information via a display:block/none-functionality. The button (and the rest of the information) would be created similarly with me having to write it in the innerHTML part of the JS, but all the ways that I've tried haven't worked and I guess it's all about me creating the divs and other DOM objects in the JS code which means that the HTML doesn't really recognize them.
Anyhow, to get more control of the code I'm now trying something like this with the HTML:

```
<div id="show_all_results">
    <div id='search_result_single'> // First results....
        <div id='search_result_from_box'>
            <span class="origin_time"></span>
            <span class="origin_name"></span>
        </div>
        <div id='search_result_divider'>
            <span>-</span>
        </div>
        <div id='search_result_to_box'>
            <span class='destination_time'></span>
            <span class='destination_name'></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id='search_result_single'> // Second results....
        <div id='search_result_from_box'>
            <span class="origin_time"></span>
            <span class="origin_name"></span>
        </div>
        <div id='search_result_divider'>
            <span>-</span>
        </div>
        <div id='search_result_to_box'>
            <span class='destination_time'></span>
            <span class='destination_name'></span>
        </div>
    </div>
...and so on.
</div>
```

The JS:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.leg.length; i++) {
    var originName = document.getElementsByClassName("origin_name");
    var originTime = document.getElementsByClassName("origin_time");
    var destTime = document.getElementsByClassName("destination_time");
    var destName = document.getElementsByClassName("destination_name");
    for (var x = 0; x < originName.length; x++) {
        var originNameItem = originName[x];
        originNameItem.innerHTML = this.leg[0].origin.name;
    }
    for (var y = 0; y < originTime.length; y++) {
        var originTimeItem = originTime[y];
        originTimeItem.innerHTML = this.leg[i].origin.time;
    }
    for (var z = 0; z < destTime.length; z++) {
        var destTimeItem = destTime[z];
        destTimeItem.innerHTML = this.leg[this.leg.length - 1].destination.time;
    }
    for (var a = 0; a < destName.length; a++) {
        var destNameItem = destName[a];
        destNameItem.innerHTML = this.leg[this.leg.length - 1].destination.name;
    }
}
```

Is there anybody that can help me get each part of the leg-array into different parts of the page using the same classes as I've done? Or is there a better way?
This became really long, sorry about that, but please let me know if I can provide any additional information. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to understand your problem here. Do you mean to say that you want to display more information about 'New York','Boston', just like how it is shown on hovering mouse?

Comment: Hi. No, I'd like to get the information of the first "leg" into the first search_result_single-div and then the information from the second "leg" into the second search_result_single-div, and so on. Thanks so much for trying to figure it out!

Comment: Ok, as per my understanding,here is what you can do.. When you are creating a div for each leg, assign a unique id to each div such as.. for(i..){var srch_div_id = "search_result_"+i;.. You can then access each div using eval function and fill in the details in that div. hope it will help..